# a tag link css not working?

Tags: css, html

I've made this css code beneath to make a class for links and to not apply the css to every a tag but just to the one with the class but it isn't working.

```
.redlink
{
color: red;
font-family: 'Finger Paint', cursive;  
}

.redlink.a.link
{
text-decoration: none;
color: red;
font-family: 'Finger Paint', cursive;
}

.redlink.a.hover
{
text-decoration: none;
color: orange;
font-family: 'Finger Paint', cursive;
}

.redlink.a.visited 
{
text-decoration: none;
color: red;
font-family: 'Finger Paint', cursive;
}

.redlink.a.active
{
text-decoration: none;
color: red;
font-family: 'Finger Paint', cursive;
}

.redlink.a.
{
text-decoration: none;
color: red;
font-family: 'Finger Paint', cursive;
}
```

Oke so the point of my code is to have the class redlink as a class to be used for the a tag, this is the first time I'm attempting this. Basically the code isn't working apart from the basic .redlink class, here's the html:

```
<a href="#" class="redlink">I should light up orange!</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.` is used in css for your own classes like you did here:

```
.redlink
{
color: red;
font-family: 'Finger Paint', cursive;  
}
```

but the part when you start adding .behind it is wrong..

If it won't be only this link that you want to have red but a link in some part of the site you can do this:

```
.redlink a:link, .redlink a:visited, .redlink a:active
{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: red;
    font-family: 'Finger Paint', cursive;
}

.redlink a:hover 
{ 
    text-decoration: none; 
    color: orange; 
    font-family: 'Finger Paint', cursive; 
}
```

if you had html:

```
<div class="redlink">
every <a href="">link</a> in this area will be red
</div>
```

If you want it just for specific one link, use the answer from Somwya.

Comment: The “Btw” note is wrong: `font-style: italic` means using an italic typeface of a font, whereas the generic name `cursive` means something completely different (and is generally implemented lousily).

Answer (score 1):

You should write like this

```
a.redlink
{
color: red;
font-family: 'Finger Paint', cursive;  
}
a.redlink:hover
{
text-decoration: none;
color: orange;
}
a.redlink:active
{
text-decoration: none;
color: red;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Wzk8c/4/)**

Also you need not to write font--family in all the classes, its enough to write once for main a tag class.

Comment: thanks, i didnt get that before,as i sad only just learned css so stupid mistake!

Comment: @Niels you can thank/help people that post answers which help you by voting them up and accepting the one that answered your question best ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can try with this

```
.redlink:hover
```